# Index behaviour (create and drop) on postgres partitioned tables

Tags: postgresql, indexing, partitioning

I have large postgres table, which is partitioned.
The table is indexed.
Indexes are created for each partition separately.
My question is:

When indexes are created, they also get created on child tables.
While dropping it is dropping only specified index in drop statement.
And showing

```
WARNING:  Only dropped the index "my_index_name"
HINT:  To drop other indexes on child partitions, drop each one explicitly.
DROP INDEX
```

How to drop indexes on child paritions, without dropping it one-by-one (as I have 255 child tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit messy, but as long as the indexes are not used by any constraints you could do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drop_child_indexes(parent text, partial text)
    RETURNS VOID AS
  $$
  DECLARE
    q text;
    x RECORD;
  BEGIN
    q := 'SELECT indexname FROM pg_catalog.pg_indexes WHERE tablename ~ '''
      || partial
      || ''' AND tablename != '''
      || parent || '''';
    FOR x IN EXECUTE q LOOP
      EXECUTE 'DROP INDEX ' || x.indexname;
      RAISE NOTICE 'Dropping index %', x.indexname;
    END LOOP;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The "parent" variable is whatever table you *don't* want to drop indexes on, the "partial" variable is a substring that matches your partition table names (this is assuming the normal situation where partitions are named things like "some_common_prefix_2013_04"). This might not be exactly what you need, but it might give you ideas

Comment: Yes did the same, ran the following query and iterated DROP INDEX for each value:                                               SELECT {column}
        FROM
        pg_indexes
        WHERE
        tablename LIKE '{table_name}%%';

Comment: Glad you figured out a way to get it done. That's a lot of child table indexes. The only really irritating part about the function I wrote is quote escaping...